# How to switch from one wifi network to another in android

Tags: android, networking, wifimanager, wifi

I am learning about WifiManager, WifiConfiguration APIs.
What i am trying to achieve is that i want to connect to a specific network.
That is my main task connecting to a **SPECIFIC NETWORK**, however if my device is already connected to some other network i want to switch from the network to my SPECIFIC NETWORK.
Here is the snippet

```
    int networkId ;
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wc.SSID = "ABCDEFG";
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);


    Log.d("Rohit", "Adding wifi config");

    networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);

    Log.d("Rohit", "Config added\ndisconnecting\nid = "+networkId);

    wifiManager.disconnect();

    Log.d("Rohit", "Disconnected\nNetwork enabling");

    wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);

    Log.d("Rohit", "enabled\n reconnecting....");

    wifiManager.reconnect();

    Log.d("Rohit","connected");
```

Here is the debugged output

> 04-08 19:57:49.690 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit: Adding wifi config
>   04-08 19:57:49.964 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit: Config added
>   04-08 19:57:49.964 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit: disconnecting
>   04-08 19:57:49.964 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit: id = 64
>   04-08 19:57:49.964 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit: Disconnected
>   04-08 19:57:49.964 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit: Network enabling
>   04-08 19:57:50.087 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit: enabled
>   04-08 19:57:50.087 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit:  reconnecting....
>   04-08 19:57:50.089 3326-3326/com.example.illuminati.services D/Rohit: connected

If the device is not connected to any network it connects to the SPECIFIC NETWORK 
But if it is connected to other network it is reconnecting to the same network again.
What am i missing here ?
I have found a similar question in stackoverflow but that doesn't help.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok After 30-40 mins of testing this worked out for me.
I created a **seperate** method to disable the currently active network.
But one thing i do not understand that in wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true); the second parameter is disableOthers .
So if i am using wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true); ,it should do the trick which is done in my **seperate** method.
**Thoughts pls?**

Here is the updated code

```
 int networkId ;
    wifiConfig = getWifiConfig();
    wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

  //  if(wifiManager.)

    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    Log.d("Rohit", "current ssid "+info.getSSID());

    boolean disable =disableCurrent(info.getSSID());
   // Log.d("Rohit","disabled ?"+disable);


    Log.d("Rohit", "Adding wifi config");
    networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    //wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);

    wifiManager.disconnect();
    Log.d("Rohit", "Config added\ndisconnecting\nid = " + networkId);
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);


    Log.d("Rohit", "Disconnected\nNetwork enabling");


    Log.d("Rohit", "enabled\n reconnecting....");
    wifiManager.reconnect();


    Log.d("Rohit", "connected");
```

And here is the seperate Method

```
public boolean disableCurrent(String ssid)
{
    List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    for(WifiConfiguration conf : configuredNetworks)
    {
        Log.d("Rohit","List "+conf.SSID);
        if(conf.SSID.equals(ssid)) {
            Log.d("Rohit","Inside");
            wifiManager.disableNetwork(conf.networkId);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```